# Using pgx to connect to postgres db in Go

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying go connect to my postgres database using the [jackc/pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx) package and I'm following the provided example. The problem is that the code gets stuck at the connect call. I've tried printing something right after it and it doesn't print.

```
var dbURL string = fmt.Sprintf("postgresql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s", user, password, host, port, dbname)

fmt.Println(dbURL)

conn, err := pgx.Connect(context.Background(), dbURL)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Unable to connect to database: %v\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
defer conn.Close(context.Background())

var text string
err = conn.QueryRow(context.Background(), "select text from questions where id=$1", 1).Scan(&text)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "QueryRow failed: %v\n", err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

fmt.Println(text)
```

Output:

```
postgresql://postgres:password@127.0.0.1:52269/database_name
```

What am I doing wrong? I can connect to the db with pgAdmin 4 and I've connected to it before using the standard sql from go.

```
connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", user, password, dbname)
a.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)
```

Comment: It doesn't go past this as I said. It doesn't return anyting. After printing the output, it gets stuck there and I have to ctrl+c. I realized the port is wrong and that fixes it. Shouldn't it give an error instead of being stuck there instead?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `postgres://...` instead of `postgresql://...`?

Comment: The sources I've seen say postgresql

Comment: @Myntekt as long as you've tried with `postgres://` and you're seeing the same issue, fair enough.

Comment: @Myntekt note also that your `dbURL` has no `sslmode` setting, while the allegedly working `connectionString` does, so maybe that's your issue?

Comment: By the way, you can use the `connectionString` instead of the URL, give it a try.

Answer (score 5):

Documentation for pgx says both connection string and URL are allowed

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool@v4.11.0#ParseConfig

## Example DSN

user=jack password=secret host=pg.example.com port=5432 dbname=mydb sslmode=verify-ca pool_max_conns=10

## Example URL

postgres://jack:secret@pg.example.com:5432/mydb?sslmode=verify-ca&pool_max_conns=10